# How to make vueitfy v-layout to cover the whole width of the screen

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to implement vuetify v-list Avatar with 3 lines using the vuetifyhttps://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#examples documentation. However the list is displayed but doesn't not cover the full width of the screen.

here is my code

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex>
        <v-list>
          <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
            <v-subheader
              v-if="item.header"
              id="item.header"
              :key="item.header"
              v-html="item.header"
            ></v-subheader>

            <v-divider
              v-else-if="item.divider"
              :key="index"
              :inset="item.inset"
            ></v-divider>

            <v-list-item v-else :key="item.title" two-line>
              <v-layout row wrap justify-space-between>
                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                  <v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-img :src="item.avatar"></v-img>
                  </v-list-item-avatar>
                </v-flex>
                <v-spacer />
                <v-flex xs12 md8>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title v-html="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
                    <v-list-item-subtitle
                      v-html="item.subtitle"
                    ></v-list-item-subtitle>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-list-item>
          </template>
        </v-list>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

[here is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy2VG.png) but i would like to increase the width to cover most of the screen if not all.

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the codepen example [a link] (https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101) on Vuetify for the Avatar with 3 lines

They have the width setup in their `v-card`

```
<v-card
      max-width="450"
      class="mx-auto"
    >
```

You should have something like this above where you start your template, maybe right below where the app is started `div id="app"`

If you don't have anything like that, try putting it in the v-container

```
<v-container max-width="1080" fluid>
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it did not solve the problem. Yes, they have their width setup in their `v-card` and I had tried using their example earlier and I even increased the width to "1080" but it didn't work. The farthest it went was setting width to`"550"` after that, the v-card width doesn't increase.

Also the second solution of using a v-container and setting the width like you recommended `<v-container max-width="1080" fluid>` had no effect at all, I tried smaller and larger widths but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it didn't work. In my `index` file (which is the parent file) in which I call the component that has this code, I had `<v-layout column wrap>` instead of `<v-layout row wrap>`.

```
<template>
  <v-container class="mx-auto">
    <v-layout column wrap>
      <v-flex>
        <MyProfile />
        <Education :items="items" />
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

This caused the width to be small. Once I changed it to row, the width of the layout expanded.